# I can`t mock a repository with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a repository but it doesnt work (before it was working).

```
@Mock
public UserRepository mockedUserRepository;

....

@InjectMocks
ClassDAOImpl daoImplSUT;

....

@Test
public void shouldTest() {
  Mockito.when(mockedUserRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(operators);

  List<User> users= daoImplSUT.getAllUsers();
}
```

I don´t know why is not working. When I debug I can check that the mocked repository is null. Then I obtain a NullPointerException.

Can you help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: `mockedUserRepository` != `mockBKUserRepository` - accident or missed?

Comment: Are you using JUnit 4 or JUnit 5? If you're on 4, have you got the MockitoJUnitRunner set in the RunWith annotation? If you're on 5 have you got the MockitoExtension set in the ExtendWith annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are no initializing mock.

1. JUnit 5: Add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in setUp before
   each test or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`annotation in the test class
2. JUnit 4: Add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` in setUp before
   each test or `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` annotaion in the test
   class

Answer (score 0):

For Junit 4:

Use @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) on you Test class:

```
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleTest {
    //...
}
```

see the docs for more information https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html

For Junit 5:

Use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) on you Test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExampleTest {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is for JUnit 4. It's done differently in JUnit 5; RunWith gets replaced with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`